# Create mapping from string to class type in scala

Tags: json, scala

I have a lot of different external JSON entities that I want to parse to different internal case classs via json4s (scala). Everything works fine via the extract function from json4s. I have implemented a parse function which takes a type and a json string and parses the string to the type / the case class. To map the correct json string to the correct case class I have implemented a pattern matching function, which looks like this

```
entityName match {
 case "entity1" => JsonParser.parse[Entity1](jsonString)
 case "entity2" => JsonParser.parse[Entity2](jsonString)
 ....
```

I don't like the repetition here and would like to do this mapping via a map like this:

```
val mapping = Map(
 "entity1" -> Entity1,
 "entity2" -> Entity2
 ....
```

With this map in place I could implement the JsonParser.parse function only once like this

```
JsonParser.parse[mapping(entityName)](jsonString)
```

This is not working, because the map is referencing to the object and not to the class type. I also tried classOf[Entity1], but this also is not working. Is there a way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Well...You are mixing run-time stuff with compile-time stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following idea from @SergGr, as a snippet to paste on Ammonite REPL:

```
{
    import $ivy.`org.json4s::json4s-native:3.6.0-M2`
    import org.json4s.native.JsonMethods.parse
    import org.json4s.DefaultFormats
    import org.json4s.JValue

    case class Entity1(name : String, value : Int)
    case class Entity2(name : String, value : Long)

    implicit val formats = DefaultFormats
    def extract[T](input : JValue)(implicit m : Manifest[T]) = input.extract[T]

    val mapping: Map[String, Manifest[_]] = Map(
        "entity1" -> implicitly[Manifest[Entity1]],
        "entity2" -> implicitly[Manifest[Entity2]]
      )

    val input = parse(""" { "name" : "abu", "value" : 1 } """)
    extract(input)(mapping("entity1")) //Entity1("abu", 1)
    extract(input)(mapping("entity2")) //Entity2("abu", 1L)
  }
```

Comment: Thanks, in combination with the answer from @SergGr it was really helpful.

Answer (score 1):

The way you want your `JsonParser.parse` to work is not possible in Scala. Scala is a strongly and statically typed language. It means that the compiler should know the types of the values at the compile time to be able to verify that you accesss only valid fields and methods on them and/or pass them as valid parameters to methods. Assuming your classes are

```
case class Entity1(value:Int, unique1:Int)
case class Entity2(value:String, unique2:String)
```

and you write

```
val parsed = JsonParser.parse[mapping("entity1")](jsonString)
```

how the compiler could know the type of `parsed` to know the type of `parsed.value` or to know that `parsed.unique1` is a valid field while `parsed.unique2` is not? The best type compiler could assign to such `parsed` is something very generic like `Any`. Of course you can downcast that `Any` to the specific type later but this means you still have to specify that type explicitly in the `asInstanceOf` which kind of defeats the whole purpose. Still, if somehow returning `Any` is OK for you, you may try to do something like this:

```
import org.json4s.jackson.JsonMethods
implicit val formats = org.json4s.DefaultFormats // or whatever Formats you actually need

val typeMap: Map[String, scala.reflect.Manifest[_]] = Map(
  "String" -> implicitly[scala.reflect.Manifest[String]],
  "Int" -> implicitly[scala.reflect.Manifest[Int]]
)

def parseAny(typeName: String, jsonString: String): Any = {
  val jValue = JsonMethods.parse(jsonString)
  jValue.extract(formats, typeMap(typeName))
}
```

and then do something like this:

```
def testParseByTypeName(typeName: String, jsonString: String): Unit = {
  try {
    val parsed = parseAny(typeName, jsonString)
    println(s"parsed by name $typeName => ${parsed.getClass} - '$parsed'")
  } catch {
    case e => println(e)
  }
}

def test() = {
  testParseByTypeName("String", "\"abc\"")
  testParseByTypeName("Int", "123")
}
```

P.S. If your `entityName` doesn't come from the outside (i.e. you don't analyze data to find out actual type), you don't actually need it at all. It is enough to use type (without a need for `match`/`case`) such as:

```
def parse[T](jsonString: String)(implicit mf: scala.reflect.Manifest[T]): T = {
  val jValue = JsonMethods.parse(jsonString)
  jValue.extract[T]
}

def testParse[T](prefix: String, jsonString: String)(implicit mf: scala.reflect.Manifest[T]): Unit = {
  try {
    val parsed = parse[T](jsonString)
    println(s"$prefix => ${parsed.getClass} - '$parsed'")
  } catch {
    case e => println(e)
  }
}

def test() = {
  testParse[String]("parse String", "\"abc\"")
  testParse[Int]("parse Int", "123")
}
```